# Mass printing ODT documents

Tags: printing, libreoffice, openoffice.org

Is there a faster way to print multiple ODT documents besides opening each one in OpenOffice/LibreOffice and printing each document separately? It would be great if I could just select multiple documents in Nautilus and have some option to print them all with the same print settings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, in Nautilus select the relevant .odt documents...

**UPDATE**:
You can **fully "automate"** the process by adding a **Nautilus Action**
`sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions`

eg (nautilus-actions setup):
Command: `ooffice -writer -p -headless`
Parameters: `%M`
Filenames: `*.odt`
`[*]` Appears if selection has multiple files of folders

---

or:
**here is my original "Terminal" version**

In Nautilus copy selected files to the clipboard (filenames are stored)...

Set up your required printer settings in OpenOffice...

In `gnome-terminal`, use the context-menu item `Paste Filenames` ...
Note: the pasted filenames are: 'single-quoted' and space delimited

- `ooffice -writer -p 'YOUR' 'PASTED' 'FILENAMES' &`

I don't know how long a Terminal command-line can handle, but it does work..
(I just tested it;  printing to a cups-pdf virtual "printer")

On newer versions of Ubuntu featuring LibreOffice instead of OpenOffice be sure to use the `libreoffice`-command instead.

---

on libreoffice you might also have to use "--" instead of "-", the full command then is:

```
libreoffice --writer -p --headless 'filename1' 'filename2'
```

Comment: A marvellous answer - I'll remember this and be very glad when I need it.

Comment: For Ubuntu 17.10 it needs to be: 
 
`libreoffice --writer -p --headless`

The parameter has to be:  

`%B`

Comment: Is there a way to also customise the print setup, e.g. paper size?

Answer (score -1):

What I think you need is a batch convert to get all your documents into pdf:

http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/01/11/from-microsoft-to-openoffice.html

Once you have pdf files, it's much easier to send them all to the printer, by joining them all up into one big pdf using `pdftk` or by using the normal print option.